# I am working an a player script for a 1st person game, can anyone help me add clamping to this rotation script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation

```cs
cameraVertical = Input.GetAxis("Camera Vertical") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
myCamera.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(cameraVertical, 0, 0);
```

I am working in unity, and I am working on my first 3D game. I started to work on rotation before getting stuck, and got help on here. now I am working on clamping the rotation within a set range. Does anyone know a good way to do so for this script? I am not really experienced with doing stuff with rotation, and nothing I have tried worked.

I have not been able to think of anything that would work for rotation, and as such I have not been able to try anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to clamp the final rotation angle after applying the input you can do something like

```
public float minVerticalAngle = -80f; // minimum vertical angle here
public float maxVerticalAngle = 80f;  // maximum vertical angle here


cameraVertical *= turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
myCamera.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(cameraVertical, 0, 0);

// Clamp the final rotation angle
Vector3 currentRotation = myCamera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, minVerticalAngle, maxVerticalAngle);
myCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
```

this approach takes the final rotation angle after applying the input and clamps it within those specified ranges. The `Mathf.Clamp` func is then used to ensure that the vertical rotation remains within those desired bounds.

Or Assuming `cameraVertical` is your rotation input

```
cameraVertical = Input.GetAxis("Camera Vertical") * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

// Adjust the camera rotation based on the input
myCamera.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(cameraVertical, 0, 0);

// Clamp the camera's local rotation to a certain range
float minRotation = -80f; // Example minimum rotation
float maxRotation = 80f;  // Example maximum rotation

Vector3 currentRotation = myCamera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, minRotation, maxRotation);

myCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
```

Hope this works out for you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're critera is here to be clamped, but you could just pass it thorough [Mathf.Clamp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to limit your values going in.

```cs
var clampedValue = Mathf.Clamp(cameraVertical, Min, Max)
myCamera.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(clampedValue , 0, 0);
```

Clamping directly on a quaternion is a little trickier but still do-able. The most readable method imo would be converting it to euler and clamping the xyz then converting back.

```cs
Vector3 rotation = myCamera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles; 

// clamp this as shown above using Mathf.clamp
rotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, Min, Max);

myCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation .z);
```

Comment: I am trying to clamp the end result, not the amount it is rotating by each time.